# Paho Client Web Socket Can't Find mqtt

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, paho

I've been given a project that is using a Paho/MQTT client through Javascript to update a web page. The project starts an http server through python on localhost:8080 and then, when the webpage is loaded, a main.js script starts the client and runs the connect as shown below:

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost",Number(8080),'0');
client.onConnectionLost = onConLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMesArvd;

console.log("start connection...");
client.connect({onSuccess: onConnect});
```

The problem is that upon trying to connect the below error appears and the onConnect method does not appear to connect as a console.log does not appear:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

The code highlighted in red in the paho-mqtt.js is below:

```
new WebSocket(a, ["mqtt"])
```

I tried adding a mqtt file to the folder localhost is being run from but it only changes the response code (301 if a mqtt folder is present, 200 if a file).

Adding the mosquitto.conf that came with the project:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883

listener 8080
protocol websockets
```

I noticed it's not in the same folder as the paho/mqtt client but in ../dir2/setup/.

I've looked around but I haven't seen anyone with this issue so any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure, your MQTT broker is configured to listen for websocket connections?

Comment: can you post broker configuration?

Comment: Post the python code, there is nothing wrong with the paho/JavaScript you've shown

Comment: Added the code for my conf file and details on its directory. Also mentioned that the onConnect method for the paho server doesn't appear to connect as a console.log call doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Santosh Balaji for pointing me in the right direction on this one.

I believe I needed to [install mosquitto](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/how-to-install-mosquitto-broker-on-raspberry-pi/) on the pi and then change the mosquitto.conf file in the mosquitto install dir to the one provided by the project. After installing and confirming my conf was being used the js and Python connected without issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Is port 8080 occupied by other process before starting mqtt. Try to start your mosquitto with conf file. It will show up error if there is anything wrong with the start.

**mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf**

2) Try changing the port to 9001 as it is default port for using websockets in mqtt